# manually editing data migration tool config files for azure devops server 2019 migration to azure devops services

Tags: azure-active-directory, database-migration, azure-devops-server-2019

SID of Azure ADDS and SID of Azure active directory is not same as per [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/migrate/migration-import?view=azure-devops#understand-the-identity-map-log-file) .. so on that note is there any way to customized the identityLogMap.csv with UPN attribute instead of SID –

Pre-requisite or migration is to Match the security identifier of On premise AD with azure AD a per [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/migrate/migration-import?view=azure-devops#understand-the-identity-map-log-file).....but in our case we don't have on premise AD and are using Azure active directory domain services(azure ADDS). where SID is autogenerated ...... in that case can i use UPN(user principle Name) to Match my users in identityLog.csv file during migration? or any other way to do it

Comment: Could you please describe your question in more detail?

Comment: have described it